# Changing the Landing page cq5 publish

Tags: java, aem

When a user enters localhost:4502 the landing page located at /content/****/****/shop.html should be loaded.

Tried [this](http://teknopoint.us/change-start-page-cq5-projects-welcome/).

Can you please suggest

1. How to acquire this a project specific?
2. How to activate this on publish environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. How to acquire this a project specific?

Copied the config folder from `/libs/cq/core/` to `/app/<project>/`

2. How to activate this on publish environment?

overridden the `com.day.cq.commons.servlets.RootMappingServlet`for publish instance.

Ref: [BLOG](https://cqinnovator.blogspot.com/2014/07/how-to-change-default-page-after-sign.html)

Comment: If you are using `config.author` or `config.publish` nodes, it will be a system wide configuration. Secondly, one instance's root can point only to one location.

Comment: That is why I am overriding the node on my project module (/apps/<projectname>/) . Hence the scope of overridden node will be only till the project.

Answer (score 1):

Go to CRXDE on your Author instance and open the `/content` node.

The resource type of this node is `sling:redirect`, its purpose is to take the user to another page when they try to a page specified by the node's `sling:target` property. This is handled by the [Sling Redirect Servlet](https://sling.apache.org/documentation/bundles/rendering-content-default-get-servlets.html#redirectservlet).

Set `sling:target` to the path of the page you want to serve (*/content/****/****/shop.html*). Save the changes.

Then go to the site admin (*Websites*) and activate the `/content` page.

Once the content change makes it to the Publish instance, your page should be served when you hit http://localhost:4503

Comment: But this will be common for the whole instance right? What if there are multiple projects in the same instance?

Comment: @GowthamiReddy then you can use [Sling Mappings](https://sling.apache.org/documentation/the-sling-engine/mappings-for-resource-resolution.html). Although how exactly is probably a subject for a question of its own, or maybe even a series of questions.

Comment: Posted the answer. Comment if I am missing anything. Thanks.